# print value of a variable in C#, xaml during kinect programming,

Tags: c#, xaml, kinect

I am an absolute beginner in kinect programming. I have written a code in C# and xaml using tutorial, http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/. This is a window store application building using blank project in XAML as suggested in tutorial.After writing the code in order to understand it, I wanted to check the value of various variable defined and used in it.

However, I could not find a way to print the value of variable. Seems like C#'s 'console.writeline' does not work here

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you one example of variable you want display ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
```